# Implementing simple upvote downvote program

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am using express.js and jQuery to create a basic upvote downvote program. Basically the voting buttons increment/decrement by one whenever pressed and the result of each button click is displayed below. Nothing happens when the buttons are clicked, not even a `Cannot POST /`. I am not sure what is causing the error. This is what my `main.js` file looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#up").click(function(){
    var up = $.post("/upvote", {changeBy: 1}, function(dataBack){

        $("#upvote").text(dataBack);
    });

});
$("#down").click(function(){
    var down = $.post("/downvote", {changeBy: 1},
    function(dataBack){
        $("#downvote").text(dataBack);
    });

  });
});
```

and then on the server side `server.js`, I have this:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

var inc = 0;
var dec = 0;

app.post("/upvote", function(req, res){
   res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
   inc += parseFloat(req.body.changeBy);
   res.write(JSON.stringify(inc));
   res.end();

});
app.post("/downvote", function(req, res){
   res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
   dec -= parseFloat(req.body.changeBy);
   res.write(JSON.stringify(dec));
   res.end();

 });


var server = app.listen(8081, function () {

    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

A bit of HTML:

```
<div class="buttons">
<button id="down">Downvote</button>
    <p id="downvote"></p>
<button id="up">Upvote</button>
    <p id="upvote"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Any error you are getting at client side?

Comment: Not that I know of. It just seems like it is not working on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I used your code to create a jsfiddle and it seems to be working fine with click events. Of course the ajax calls error out but the click event handler itself seems to be called Chrome at least.

```
<div class="buttons">
<button id="down">Downvote</button>
    <p id="downvote"></p>
<button id="up">Upvote</button>
    <p id="upvote"></p>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#up").click(function(){
    var up = $.post("/upvote", {changeBy: 1}, function(dataBack){

        $("#upvote").text(dataBack);
    });

});
$("#down").click(function(){
    var down = $.post("/downvote", {changeBy: 1},
    function(dataBack){
        $("#downvote").text(dataBack);
    });

  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j14qkyae/

Comment: Yeah. I am wondering if something is wrong with my server.js setup.

Answer (score 0):

i gave this a try and it works. Is this really the whole html you use? Then this is the error. You need to in include jquery and your main.js into the html. I copied a query.min.js into the public directory of the server.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Up Down Vote</title>
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button id="down">Downvote</button>
    <p id="downvote"></p>
    <button id="up">Upvote</button>
    <p id="upvote"></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have this: <title>Upvote Downvote</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

Comment: PS: Of course this index.hml, main.js and query.min.js are all in the public folder.